# Is there a standard way to choose tick locations for an axis in a plot?

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, plot

When marking tick locations on a plot, are there any standard solutions to how to place the tick markers? I looked at Matplotlib's MaxNLocator (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L1212) but it's not immediately clear what all the different options do, or which of them are necessary for basic tick placement.

Can someone provide pseudocode for a simple tick location function?

Comment: Can you give us a more concrete question?  With the level of generality here I would just point you back at `matplotlib.ticker`.  You might find it easier to read the docs http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

Comment: As a more concrete question, suppose I have a bar chart with bar values ranging from b0 to b1. Where should I put the ticks on the bar chart?

Comment: by concrete example I mean one with some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the rule of thumb for placing ticks on a plot is to use multiples of 1, 2, 5, and 10.  In my experience, `matplotlib` seems to abide by this.  If you have reason to deviate from the default ticks, I think the easiest way to set them is to use the `set_ticks()` method for a particular axis.  The relevant documentation is here: http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html.

### Example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot()                        # create axes to plot into
foo = np.array([0, 4, 12, 13, 18, 22])    # awkwardly spaced data
bar = np.random.rand(6)                   # random bar heights
plt.bar(foo, bar)                         # bar chart
ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()                   # check tick locations -- currently array([  0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.,  25.])

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(foo)                   # set the ticks to be right at each bar
ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()                   # array([ 0,  4, 12, 13, 18, 22]) 
plt.draw()

ax.xaxis.set_ticks([0, 10, 20])           # minimal set of ticks
ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()                   # array([ 0, 10, 20])
plt.draw()
```

Of the three options in my example, I would keep the default behaviour in this case; but there are definitely times when I would override the defaults.  For example, another rule of thumb is that we should minimize the amount of ink in our plots that is not data (i.e. markers and lines).  So if the default tick set was `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, I might change that to `[0, 2, 4, 6]`, since that's less ink for the plot ticks without losing clarity.

**Edit**: The ticks at `[0, 10, 20]` can also be accomplished with locators, as suggested in the comment.  Examples:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.FixedLocator([0,10,20]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(base=10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(nbins=3))
```

Comment: The `Locator` classes will do much of his for you.

Comment: @tcaswell: edited the answer to include `Locator` examples.  Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?